# Volume of a solid region enclosed by elliptic cylinder

Tags: calculus

> Problem:Find the volume of the solid $D$ enclosed by $$\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2\leq 1, \    z\geq 0, \ x-\frac{3}{2}z+1\geq 0$$

Well, I actually found the answer by integrating;
$$\int_{0}^2\int_{\frac{3}{2}z-1}^2 2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}\ dx\ dz=\frac{8}{9}\pi+\sqrt{3}$$

But this process included trig-substitution and I needed to integrate $\sin^{-1}x$, use integration by parts, which was very complicated calculations.

Can anyone give me any other ideas to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{0}^{\frac{2(x+1)}{3}}$dzdydx

Projection onto XY PLane is ellipse

$\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2 = 1$

To simplify matters here, use change of variables by putting $x=2cos\theta$ , $y=sin\theta$

Comment: May I ask for further explanation about how to set the boundaries for the triple integral?

Comment: You are required to find volume of a  3D figure whose base is ellipse and roof is plane given by equation x - 3/2z +1 =0. So you draw a raw from base until it hits plane and you have your z limits. projection in xy plane is ellipse so this double integral can be solved by change of variables (you are transforming ellipse to unit circle  by this ).

Comment: Hmm But isn't the base 'a part of the ellipse'? Since the given plane intersects the elliptic cylinder. Why is the projection onto the xy plane an ellipse?

Comment: The plane is extended in infinite direction, but we are considering that volume which is above ellipse